# Ajax link inside loaded content

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I got problem using ajax->link inside a loaded view.

In my index page, i load dynamically a div with the content of a view. Inside this view i got a ajax->link to update content in itself.

If i go on the view, the update work correctly.
Therefore, if in try in the loaded div, it doesn't work.

Firebug, notice me when i load the div :

```
registry is undefined
     var respondersForEvent = registry.get(eventName);
```

Is it any solution about this ?

Comment: What are you using for the Ajax? Plain Javascript, jQuery, Prototype, etc.? The problem is when the content loads via ajax, it is not registered with the DOM. You need to run a function or somehow get the new Ajax call registered so the DOM tree sees that it exists.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this would be to use something like the [jquery .live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which will do the magic for you. If thats useful and you want to move from prototype, have a look at [this jquery helper](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jozek000/2010/09/21/ajax-helper-with-jquery).

Comment: Hi, thx for your responses. In fact i'm not a big expert on javascript stuff, that why i choose to code throught a framework. So i use standard lib (prototype) and the standard ajax helper. Is there any similar solution with Prototype ?

Comment: I find something about Event#findElement ?! I don't really know how to use it with ajax->link ...

Comment: The problem is as cdburgess described. I don't think findElement will work since the new html isn't registered in the DOM. You'll either need to rethink the way you post the data (probably remove that particular ajax functionality) or it will take more js work.